# I have trouble getting depth information from the DEPTH16 format with the Camera2 API using ToF on P30 pro

Tags: android-camera

I am currently testing options for depth measurement with the smartphone and wanted to create a depth image initially for testing. I am using the Camera2Basic example as a basis for this. (https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic) Using Depth16 I get a relatively sharp "depth image" back. But the millimetres are not correct. They are in a range around from 3600mm to 5000mm for an object like a wall that is about 500mm or 800mm away from the camera.
But what puzzles me the most is that the image does not transmit any information in the dark. If Android is really targeting the ToF sensor for DEPTH16, it shouldn't be affected in the dark, should it? Or do I have to use AR-Core or Huawei's HMS core to get a real ToF image?

I am using a Huawei P30 Pro and the code for extracting the depth information looks like this. And yes performance wise it is bullshit but it is only for testing purposes:)

```
    private Map<String, PixelData> parseDepth16IntoDistanceMap(Image image) {

        Map<String, PixelData> map = new HashMap();
        Image.Plane plane = image.getPlanes()[0];
        // using asShortBuffer() like in the documentation leads to a wrong format (for me) but does not help getting better values
        ByteBuffer depthBuffer = plane.getBuffer().order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int stride = plane.getRowStride();
        int offset = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (short y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (short x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                short depthSample = depthBuffer.getShort( (y / 2) * stride + x);
                short depthSampleShort = (short) depthSample;
                short depthRange = (short) (depthSampleShort & 0x1FFF);
                short depthConfidence = (short) ((depthSampleShort >> 13) & 0x7);
                float depthPercentage = depthConfidence == 0 ? 1.f : (depthConfidence - 1) / 7.f;
                maxz = depthRange;
                sum = sum + depthRange;
                numPoints++;
                listOfRanges.add((float) depthRange);
                if (depthRange < minz && depthRange > 0) {
                    minz = depthRange;
                }
                map.put(x + "_" + y, new PixelData(x, y, depthRange, depthPercentage));
                i++;
            }
           
        }
        return map;
    }
```

In any case, it would help a lot to know if you can get the data this way at all, so I know if I'm already doing something fundamentally wrong. Otherwise I will change to one of the ar systems. Either way, many thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a depth map where you can see the distance to an object you might use ARCORE Depth API.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/overview

Or you can follow the codelab where shows you how to get the data in millimeters.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-depth#0

Comment: I thought I could bypass the heavyweight ar-core for my little prototype, since the Camera2Basic example offers a depth option.  I'm also experimenting with ar-core on the side. I was just wondering why I get a Depth16 image from the Camera2 API, but it apparently doesn't serve the ToF sensor. At least with my configuration.